# How to use string tokenizers and buffers.

Tags: java, string, parsing, stringtokenizer, stringbuffer

I'm working on a program to reverse a phone number, remove all delimiters, and compare it to the original number to determine if it is a palindrome. It will also convert the phone number to an integer with commas. I am having several issues. I am getting errors and don't know why. Also, it will not correctly determine whether the number is a palindrome or not. Any help would be appreciated.

```
//Phone String Palindrome Conversions
//This program will turn a phone number around and check to see if it is a palindrome
//This program will remove all deasdspace and symbols from the phone number
//This program will reverse the string and compare it to the original
//This program will put a phone number in a long intiger format
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
public class DottinoN_palindrome
{
  public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
{
    String phoneshort1;
    boolean pal;
BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.println("Please enter your phone number");
String phone1=br.readLine();
phoneshort1 = spaceremover(phone1);
System.out.println(phoneshort1);
pal = palindrometest(phoneshort1);
System.out.println(pal);
if(pal = false)
{
  System.out.println("Your phone number is a palindrome!");
}
else if(pal = true)
  System.out.println("Your phone number is not a palendrome...");
numberformat(phoneshort1);

}
public static String spaceremover (String phone2)
{
String phoneshort = "";
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(phone2,"()- " ,false);
while(st.hasMoreTokens())
{
  phoneshort += st.nextToken();
}
return phoneshort;
}
public static boolean palindrometest (String phoneshort2)
{
boolean pal;
StringBuffer br = new StringBuffer(phoneshort2);
String phonebkwd = br.reverse().toString();
if(phonebkwd == phoneshort2)
{
  pal = true;
}
else pal = false;
System.out.println(phonebkwd + "--" + phoneshort2);
return pal;

}
public static void numberformat (String phoneshort2)
{
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0,000,000,000");
int number = Integer.parseInt(phoneshort2);
System.out.println("Your phone number as an intiger is: " + formatter.format(number) );
}
}
```

Comment: Please mark the appropriate answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are really some issues in your programs,

1. as wipindipy10 said, change string comparison with equal method
2. if condition to print whether is palindrome, change to that

   ```
   if (!pal) {
       System.out.println("Your phone number is a palindrome!");
   } else {
       System.out.println("Your phone number is not a palendrome...");
   }
   ```
3. as you mentioned the exception happened near the bottom. This may be that the phone you input exceed the Integer.MAX_VALUE, that is 2147483647 [0x7fffffff]

Comment: It should be just pal and not !pal.

Comment: Excellent! it's working now. I changed the Integer to a Long, and used !pal and pal. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are comparing Strings, use the method equals.

From

```
    if(phonebkwd == phoneshort2)
```

Change it to

```
    if(phonebkwd.equals(phoneshort2))
```

Also, please specify the error you are getting.

Comment: int number = Integer.parseInt(phoneshort2); Its near the bottom and is causing the program to crash. im not sure if this is the problem line or if something else I have is causing this to not work. Thank you

Comment: Check your condition for printing "Your phone number is a palindrome!" and "Your phone number is not a palendrome..." It should be the other way around.

Comment: Okay, I did that, but I am still getting an error sometimes and my phone number is always a palindrome. I cant seem to figure out why.

Comment: Your comparison. Remember to use == when comparing two values. Also, when your condition statement is boolean, you can just use "if(bVal)" for true or "if(!bVal)" for false. You can change your code to just if...else

Comment: The error won't show if your input have less than or equal to 10 digits. Question: Do you have a limit to the number of digits allowed?

Comment: no, there is no limit on them. i'll try using bVal though.

Answer (score 0):

There are many errors in the code.
For string comparison use equals method

```
if(phonebkwd.equals(phoneshort2))
```

Your following if statement is wrong

```
if(pal = false)
{
  System.out.println("Your phone number is a palindrome!");
}
else if(pal = true)
  System.out.println("Your phone number is not a palendrome...");
```

You should swap if , else block.
Last error for Integer.parseInt(phoneshort2);seems to be you are trying to parse a number which is greater than Integer.MAX_VALUE